# Как добавить "живое" общение телеграмм боту. Как прописать диалог с пользователем с большим количеством переменных в ответах пользователя?

Tags: python, telebot, диалог

Хочу создать бота для общения, но не знаю как реализовать это. Как реализовать диалог в стиле вопрос/ответ без четкого ответа. Т.е

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp = 'rfr ltkf|как дела|кд|как ты|как у тебя дела|как твои дела|как жизнь')
def How_are_you(message):
    response = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(comands.How_are_you))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(response, good)
def good(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'хорошо':
        response = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(answer.positive_response))
else:
    if message.text.lower() == 'плохо':
        response = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(answer.negative_answer))
    else:
        if message.text.lower() == 'нормально':
            response = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random.choice(answer.neutral_answer))
```

но это бредово, ограниченно, массивно и т.д. Создать БД? Но инфы по этому вопросу я не нашел. Либо не попалась, либо пропустил, либо не понял. Нашел какой то пример кода, но он не заработал. Я в этом деле профан, и делаю бота чисто для себя. Что то простое по типу кода выше я понял как сделать, но вот как сделать что то сложнее я уже не понимаю. Как создать диалог по типу:
Юз - Как дела? (пример)
бот - отлично. а твои?
Юз - тоже отлично (переменная)
бот - рад за тебя (зависит от ответа Юз)
Юз - спасибо (переменная)
бот - да не за что (зависит от ответа Юз)
Это лишь пример, но надеюсь наглядный. В общем всё сводится к более сформулированному вопросу "Как прописать диалог с пользователем с большим количеством переменных в ответах пользователя?"

Comment: Можно подкрутить небольшую gpt обученную в формат chitchat к [примеру эту](https://huggingface.co/inkoziev/rugpt_chitchat). Ещё есть [ChatterBot](https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/)  если без неиронок.